# Prove $f( n ) = O( n )$ for any integer $\geqslant 1$, if $f( 1 ) = 1$ and $f( n ) = 2 f(\lfloor n/2\rfloor) + 1$ for $n\geqslant 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

$f$ is defined recursively: $\Bbb{Z}_+$ to $\Bbb{Z}_+$

How should I go on to tackle it?  I don't know where to start?

Do I compute $f( 1 )$, $f( 2 )$, and so on to see if there's anything?

Comment: Your notation l n / 2 l is ambiguous. What is the value of$\ $ l 5 / 2 l?

Comment: 2.5, it's the absolute value notation.

Comment: Are you sure? Then for any integer $n$,  l n / 2 l = n/2, so the absolute value is useless. Isn't it $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ or $\lceil n/2 \rceil$?

Comment: Ohhh, my bad. It is ⌊n/2⌋.

Comment: OK, I will edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction, 
$$ n\le f(n)\le 2n-1.$$

Comment: Can you elaborate more? How do you come up with 2n - 1?